# Number between a and b - non-inclusive on a, inclusive on b

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

(I'm a little new to SQL) I have a lot of queries I'm re-writing which have a `where` clause like this:

```
where some_number > A
and some_number <= B
```

I want to use a single `where` clause (fewer lines, it isn't faster/slower is it?) like this:

```
where some_number between A and B
```

The problem is the first clause is exclusive on A and inclusive on B. Is there any way I can specify "inclusivisity" on a single line like the second query? Thanks.

Comment: The first example is the proper syntax.  `between` is inclusive.

Comment: If you're dealing with integers, just offset one of your limits by one. But why are you trying to do this? You're creating code that is less maintainable and no faster. What's wrong with the 2 line approach?

Comment: @DavidM - Each his own offcourse but I prefer the `BETWEEN` syntax over the `.. > A AND ... <= B`.

Comment: You do it the way you're already doing it.  Don't be tempted by the `BETWEEN (A+smallAmount) AND (B)` unless you are working with ***discrete*** values such as INTEGERs.  If you're working with ***continuous*** values such as FLOATs or DATEs, stick with what you're doing.

Comment: @Lieven - But I prefer correct mathmatical behaviour.  If the field is a continuous value, `BETWEEN` is incorrect.

Comment: @Lieven - even if you have a magic "off by one" or "off by a very small amount" to make BETWEEN jump through hoops it wasn't meant to? That's what I meant by less maintainable. I prefer BETWEEN if it is the right tool for the job, it's just that here, it isn't.

Comment: @everyone ;) Thanks for the tips. I will accept an answer (in 5 minutes) which reflects the sentiments most of you have shared.

Comment: @Dems - Right offcourse. I'll rephrase, *I prefer he `BETWEEN` syntax over the `.. > A AND ...<= B` when using discrete values.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of points...

Firstly, it's only "fewer lines" if you use fewer lines. I would format it like this:

```
where some_number > A and some_number <= B
```

because it's really one *range* condition with each end of the range coded separately.

Secondly, it's actually no faster or slower than the between version, because under the covers `between A and B` gets converted to:

```
where (some_number >= A) and (some_number <= B)
```

so the performance is identical.

Basically, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just offset your a by "+1"

Or just use your first syntax, it's easier to read.

Comment: The `+1` assumes integer. What about FLOATs and DATETIMEs, etc? The offset mechanism *only* works well for discrete values, and extremely poorly for continuous values.